# CC65 for C64 - relocate program in memory

Tags: c, c64

I use CC65 to write some program for a C64. The program compiles to like 5k of machine code. Since it starts at $0840, it overlaps with the character ram at $3000.
Is there any "pragma" or something to move my code to a higher memory segment?
My map file says:

```
Segment list:
-------------
Name                   Start     End    Size  Align
----------------------------------------------------
ZEROPAGE              000002  00001B  00001A  00001
LOADADDR              0007FF  000800  000002  00001
EXEHDR                000801  00080C  00000C  00001
STARTUP               00080D  00083F  000033  00001
CODE                  000840  004ED3  004694  00001 <---
RODATA                004ED4  004ED9  000006  00001
DATA                  004EDA  004F1D  000044  00001
INIT                  004F1E  004F39  00001C  00001
BSS                   004F3A  004F44  00000B  00001
ONCE                  004F3A  004F5F  000026  00001
```

Comment: https://cc65.github.io/doc/c64.html#ss4.1 <- `--start-addr` in the compiler?

Comment: See: https://cc65.github.io/doc/ld65.html#config-files It has info on the MEMORY and SEGMENT sections of the config file. Apparently, you have to change both. It gives a c64 example

Comment: I can't get it to work. What's the minimalist cfg file I could use for tinkering?